# Bokeh scatter plot with coloring based on 3rd variable

Tags: python, plot, data-science, bokeh

I am trying to use the following code to produce a simple scatter plot with coloring based on a third, continuous variable. When I run the code, I get no output, no error. Any Bokeh experts out there??

````
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, ContinuousColorMapper

TOOLS='pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset'
p = figure(tools=TOOLS)

color_mapper = ContinuousColorMapper(palette='Viridis256', low=min(z), high=max(z))

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z})

p.scatter(x='x', y='y', color={'field': 'z', 'transform': color_mapper}, size=8, source=source)

show(p)```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you open JavaScript console in your browser, you will see the relevant error, albeit it's not that clear.

`ContinuousColorMapper` is an abstract class. Use `LinearColorMapper` instead.